# iOS Apps Suspend Timeout

Tags: ios, iphone

I wan my Apps to stay in background when the user click on the "Home" button, but only limit to a predefine timeout (say 5 minutes).

So within 5 minutes, the Apps can be restore to where it suspended.

If the user restore it after 5 minutes, the Apps should relaunch, similar to the behaviour when we have setting UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = YES.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, this is not possible exactly as stated. To achieve the same effect, simply record the time that your app becomes inactive and perform a check when it becomes active, again. If the app was inactive for greater than the desired interval (five minutes), reset any application state, yourself.

That said, I cannot think of a situation in which this would be a good user experience. I'd strongly suggest reevaluating whether this is the *right* problem to be solving. Are you trying to solve a performance issue?

Comment: This is an apps that does monetary transaction, it would somehow required the user to read a code from SMS to proceed to the payment. Therefore within the session period, the user definitely has the right to back to his previous screen, and in the other hand, no.

Answer (score 0):

Consider approaching this problem in a different way. Instead of trying to manage background execution save the time when the application enters the background. Compare against that time when the application resumes to determine if you should restore state or start from scratch.